# Clog before 90 bend

Tags: plumbing, toilet, clog

We recently had a first floor 1/2 bath added. The waste pipe is chronically clogging. My family is aware of the problem and are careful. Every time a guest visits, we get a clog. Toilet paper seems to be the problem. I’ve run a snake from the clean out 3 times and paid a professional drain service once.  That’s 4 clogs in 6 months.

Question: is this faulty installation?  Is the bend inappropriate?  The run before the bend is about 8 ft and drops about 2 inches over that run.

The toilet and sink are opposite one another  directly above the 8 foot run in the first picture. I run the snake from the clean out.

[image][image]

Comment: For clarity, is the toilet the one that enters in the first picture, or is it further down the line to the right? It's a bit unclear from where your "toilet" arrow is pointing. Otherwise, very well done! Just curious - to you run the snake in from the toilet, or from the clean out noted in the 2nd picture?

Comment: Edited. Other things I wonder: is there some construction debris stuck in there?  It was actually a gut renovation. When I run the snake, it doesn’t seem like a ton of toilet paper comes by.  Also I can’t get the snake past the point of clog.  But I have a crappy snake. So to speak.

Comment: Have you tried snaking from the fixture end instead of the cleanout end? If there is, as you suspect, something other than TP lodged in there, it may get it from the other end. Also, consider renting a powered snake. I've done that and it had a big spring steel end - effectively a cutter head that scraped against the pipe walls and coiled through the whole diameter of the pipe. It had teeth to grind against anything it ran into. Plus, it's powered and can be had in 50', 100' and longer lengths to get the whole pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I know you've all been waiting for the exciting conclusion.  After posting here, I bought an endoscope on Amazon and zip tied it to my snake.  It just so happens that the toilet clogged again a couple days ago.  Using the endoscope and snake I was able to verify the clog -- full of toilet paper.  I unclogged the bend and then fed the snake and endoscope back up. The result is shown in the photo below.  There appears to be a lid of some sort stuck in the final bend.  I'll be calling the contractor to come and clean up his work.

[image: Some sort of lid stuck in the 90 deg bend]

Comment: Paint can lid??

Comment: Yikes! Glad you figured it out and thanks for coming back to let us know (and for accepting your own answer).